# How to get followers list on Instabot

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, instagram, instagram-api

can someone please explain me how to to get the followers list on Instabot?
So far what i wrote as test is:

```
from instabot import Bot

bot = Bot()
bot.login()
followers = bot.get_user_followers("danbilzerian")
for follower in followers:
    print(follower)
```

When I run it I can only insert my login and password and then nothing happen.
I already read documentation and examples but no luck.

I'm missing something?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you follow my steps?
Execute ipython from the terminal.

```
from instabot import Bot
bot = Bot()
bot.login()
```

Enter usernama `username_value`

Enter password `password_value`

> n
>
> 1

```
followers = bot.get_user_followers("danbilzerian")
```

[image]